# Modular question. Need help please

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Solve the equation
$$x^2+6x+10 \equiv 0 \pmod {17}$$

Comment: What have you tried yourself? There are only $17$ options for $x$ to try, and you'll find one pretty quickly if you try them in the obvious order.

Comment: The usual formula $$x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$ still works, except that square roots mean something else modulo $17$ than they do in the real numbers. For instance, $\sqrt 2$ is $6$ (or $-6 \equiv 11$, whichever you prefer).

Comment: @Servaes So x can equal 1 or 10. Is trial and error like this a valid way to solve or is there another way?

Comment: @Arthur Wouldn't that end up as (-6 +- sqrt(-4))/2 Which wouldn't have any real solutions? or can you have - squareroots in different modulos?

Comment: As suggested by Arthur, if you are solving modulo a prime then the quadratic equation still works, though you will need to take square roots modulo that prime which can take some work. For small primes trial and error is often quicker.

Comment: @Suoria As I said, square roots work differently mod $17$. Remember that $-4$ is the same as $+13$.

Comment: Modulo $17$ we have $4^2=16\equiv-1$, so $\sqrt{-1}=\pm4$ and hence $\sqrt{-4}=2\sqrt{-1}=\pm8$.

Comment: @Servaes What about -7 doesn't that work?

Comment: @Suoria $(-7)^2=49\equiv15\pmod{17}$, if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Brute-force approach:**

$$\small
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
x & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\ \hline
x^2 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 9 & 16 & 8 & 2 & 15 & 13 & 13 & 15 & 2 & 8 & 16 & 9 & 4 & 1
\\ \hline
6x & 0 & 6 & 12 & 1 & 7 & 13 & 2 & 8 & 14 & 3 & 9 & 15 & 4 & 10 & 16 & 5 & 11 \\ \hline
x^2 +6x & 0 & 7 & 16 & 10 & 6 & 4 & 4 & 6 & 10 & 16 & 7 & 0 & 12 & 9 & 8 & 9 & 12 \\ \hline
x^2+6x+10 & 10 & 0 & 9 & 3 & 16 & 14 & 14 & 16 & 3 & 9 & 0 & 10 & 5 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 5
 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: What about -7? or numbers not between 0 and 16?

Comment: @Suoria We're working $\mod17$, so it suffices to deal with numbers between $0$ and $16$, as for all other numbers, such as $-7$, there would be some $j\in\{0,\ldots,16\}$ such that $j\equiv $ that number modulo $17$, and for the case of $-7$ we would have  $j\equiv-7\pmod{17}$.

Comment: What about non integer x??

Comment: @Prasanna Didn't the problem assume from the beginning that $x\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Workaholic Data about x is not given

Comment: @Prasanna It can be easily shown, by contradiction, that if $x=p/q$ and $x$ satisfies that equation then necessarily $q=1$, hence $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Workaholic I didn't understand how you are trying to prove q=0, but solving using quadratic yields $x=-3\pm\sqrt{17k-1}$ as a solution. You may substitute and see it in the equation. For example see $-3\pm\sqrt{33}$

Comment: @Prasanna First assume that $x=p/q$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and that $q\neq1$. Substituting $x=p/q$ in $x^2+6x+10=17k$ yields $\tfrac{p^2+6pq+10q^2}{q^2}=17k$, can you now show that $q|p^2$? What can you  say about $\gcd(p,q)$ then?

Comment: @Workaholic Nice drawing, horrible solution. Would you try the same for $65537$ instead of $17$?

Comment: @egreg I only posted it as an alternative solution. I'm fully aware that brute-force approaches are usually 'horrible'.

Comment: @Workaholic You assumed only rationals, what about irrationals??

Comment: @Prasanna In that case we would have $-$ as you wrote earlier $-$ that $x=-3\pm\sqrt{17k-1}$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

Complete the square: $x^2+6x+10 = (x+3)^2+1$.

So you need to solve $(x+3)^2 \equiv -1 \equiv 16 = 4^2 \bmod 17$.

Because $17$ is prime, we get $x+3 \equiv \pm 4 \bmod 17$ and so $x\equiv 1,10 \bmod 17$.

Comment: Wait, so there are three answers to a quadratic?

Comment: Right, thanks :) So only the answers between 0 and 17 are different than others.

Comment: @lhf Maybe the downvoter wanted you to emphasize the fact that $17$ is prime, so from $a^2\equiv b^2\pmod{17}$ you can deduce $a\equiv b\pmod{17}$ or $a\equiv -b\pmod{17}$. I can think to nothing else, excluding plain silliness.

Comment: @egreg, good point, I've edited my answer, thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 1):

Lets see:

$x^2+6x+10 \equiv 0 \pmod {17}$

This implies for some integer $k$

$x^2+6x+10 =17k$ (or)

$x^2+6x+10-17k=0$

Solving the Quadratic

$$x = \frac{-6 \pm \sqrt{(-6)^2 - 4(10-17k)} }{2}$$
$$x=-3\pm\sqrt{17k-1}$$

Therefore we get the solution set of all $x$ satisfying the given equation(modular) given by $x=-3\pm\sqrt{17k-1}$ where k is an integer greater than or equal to 1.